How to make new gnu screen(tab) next to current one(tab) rather than at the end?
I use gnu screen daily. I love it.
Whenever I make new window in screen, It automatically create it at the end.
I'd like to make new window right next to current one to switch easily between them.
Is there any way to do it?
this is current my .screenrc file:
https://github.com/av930/.proFILEs/blob/master/.screenrc
below script is used to make new window from .screenrc
bind , 'screen' #simply send command screen


Anybody update?
